# Set of Lipschitz Continuous Functions and its Complement are Dense in C[a,b]

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

We define $M_{K}$ = {$f: [a,b]\to R $ |$\forall x,y \in [a,b]$ $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|$}

and let M = $\cup_{K>0} M_{K}$

I want to show that $M$ and its complement are dense in $C[a,b]$.

In my attempt, I have proved the following:

1. $M$ is an algebra, and $\forall x \in [a,b]$ $ \exists f\in M $ s.t $f(x) \neq 0$

$\forall x,y \in [a,b]$ $ x\neq y$ $ \exists f\in M$ s.t $ f(x) \neq f(y)$

and concluded by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem that $M$ is dense in $C[a,b]$

2. I then proved that $M$ is closed and then concluded that $M^{\perp}$ is closed as well. This I believe implies that $M^{\perp}$ has a complete orthonormal set in $C[a,b]$ which implies $M^{\perp}$ is dense.

Is the second method correct, which implies it suffices to show $M$ is closed in a Hilbert space, implying the question? (is 1. irrelevant if we prove $M$ is closed?)

I have wrongly interpreted the complement as $M^{\perp}$

Thanks,

Comment: You must have misread the problem. Does it actually say $M^\perp$? Or does it use the word "complement"? See, $M^\perp$ is $0$.

Comment: it does indeed say complement..

Comment: Well then I don't think it means orthogonal complement. The complement of  $M$ would be just the set of continuous functions not in $M$.

Comment: ok I will attempt to follow my first method on the complement. thx

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich having no success in showing the complement is an algebra (closed to addition, scalar multiplication, and function multiplication). any advice?

Comment: The complement is not an algebra! A set of functions can be dense in $C[0,1]$ without being an algebra.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich is there a simpler way to show the complement is dense in C[a,b] other then directly finding a sequence of functions that are not K lipchitz for all K and converge to a continuous function?

Comment: Hint: Say $F_0$ is continuous but not Lipschitz. Say $f$ is continuous. You've shown there is a sequence $f_n$ of Lipschitz functions that converge uniformly to $f-F_0$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich so I showed (hopefully without making a mistake) that if I add a lipschitz function to a non-lipschitz function I get a non lipschitz function. then by your clue: $f_{n} + F_{0}$ is in the complement and converges to $f$. was that your meaning?

Comment: Yes. It's a funny thing: If $X$ is a normed vector space, $Y$ is a _proper_ subspace and $Y$ is dense in $X$ then it follows that the complement $X\setminus Y$ is dense in $X$ as well.